# How did the Spanish-speaking ghost get recorded?

Tags: the-sixth-sense

How Malcolm ends up believing that Cole isn’t insane is that  in one tape recording of Vincent a man can be heard extremely quietly repeating

> Yo no quiero morir

over and over.

How did a ghost get caught by the tape recorder? Have the writers explained this, or is there any evidence in the film as to what caused it?

Answer (score 1):

A likely possibility is [Electronic Voice Phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_voice_phenomenon), a theory that posits that ghosts can be audible to anyone, but just speak at too low of a volume to be heard, and generally only for short periods, requiring combing through amplified segments of silence to find snippets of the ghost's speech.

> Within ghost hunting and parapsychology, electronic voice phenomena (EVP) are sounds found on electronic recordings that are interpreted as spirit voices that have been either unintentionally recorded or intentionally requested and recorded. Parapsychologist Konstantīns Raudive, who popularized the idea in the 1970s, described EVP as typically brief, usually the length of a word or short phrase.

I've found no quotes indicating that Shyamalan intended this to be the case, but based on how often *The Sixth Sense* gets listed as an example on EVP pages, it seems to be a fairly common fan theory.

Comment: Wait a minute.  It's been a while since I've seen the movie, but wasn't Malcolm already dead himself by then.  Maybe since he was a ghost himself he could hear a "recorded" ghost voice but wouldn't have been able to detect it if he'd still been alive.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt: That is also possible.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt you should post that as an answer